# Missing DLL's on deploying .Net core into ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, asp.net-core

Hi I am finding hard time to deploy my sample .net core application into ubuntu. Initially i followed http://blog.bobbyallen.me/2017/05/01/deploying-and-hosting-asp-net-core-applications-on-ubuntu-linux/ this blog and successfully able to deploy this sample application on ubuntu. This particular application is in .net core 1.0. I have created sample application in VS2017 with .Net core 2.0. I am successfully able to install .net and nginx into ubuntu. Whenever i hit `sudo -u www-data dotnet /var/webapps/Core/Core.dll` 
I get following error

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (Core.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml
```

Also I observed in the Sample solution(lk2) whenever we pubish the application using the command `sudo dotnet publish -c Release -o /var/webapps/lk2` i see lot of dlls will come in the below path. I have added the screen shot 
[image]
Same thing when i do sudo dotnet publish -c Release -o /var/webapps/Core Only below files i can see. I have added screen shot below.

[image]
After observing this i feel this is place where i am missing all required DLL's. I am just assuming this because my error message says missing  package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'. I have my solution in the GIT also at https://github.com/NiranjanAbb/Core.git. Can someone help me to fix this issue? since one week i am making my hands dirty to learn the deployment of .net into ubuntu. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: What version of dotnet-hosting do you have installed ?

Comment: Dotnet version 2.0 I installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: May I know which version I should install?

Comment: dotnet-hosting is a different package that is needed for hosting. Try to install that, version 2.0.3. This should add the missing ddls to your local runtime store.

Comment: Separate? In visual studio or Ubuntu? How can I install that?

Comment: I have installed sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 417A0893 
. so do I need to install other than this?

Comment: I am not sure, I think the package name is dotnet-host. So you can run `sudo apt-get install dotnet-host` on ubuntu.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161367/discussion-between-anserk-and-niranjan-godbole).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing the `dotnet-hosting` package...

Before installing the hosting package you’ll need to install the “dotnet product feed”. You can find it here - https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu or for our new Ubuntu 16.04 server you can run this:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-xenial-prod xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'`

Make sure you update your apt-get or you wont be able to install any of the .NET core packages, then install the hosting package:

Update the packages on your system:

`sudo apt-get update`

Install the Linux Server Hosting runtime & store:

`sudo apt-get install dotnet-hosting-2.0.0`

If you're interested I've written a blog on hosting ASP.NET Core on Linux which can be found here - https://www.tonyranieri.com/blog/2017/10/27/Hosting-.Net-Core-On-Linux/

Comment: thanks for your help tony. I have followed same steps but still i am getting same error. I hvae installed dotnet hosting package and this is installed inside /usr/share/dotnet/. I will add the screen shot what i have inside dotnet folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [dotnet-packaging](https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging). It includes a `dotnet deb` command line utility which allows you to create a `.deb` file (i.e. a Ubuntu installer) which you can use to install your app on Ubuntu. It should make deployment easier for you.

To get started, you'll first need to add this section to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Packaging.Targets" Version="0.1.45" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-deb" Version="0.1.45" />
<ItemGroup>
```

Then, run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet deb -c Release -r ubuntu.18.04-x64 -f netcoreapp2.0`. This will create a `.deb` file you can use to deploy your application to Ubuntu.

Let me know how that goes!